# Kelly Criterion for game with payoff equal to normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, game-theory

I'm struggling to come up with an answer to a problem I've asked myself, if the answer is out there I must not be searching for the correct things. The problem formulation is this:

You're given the opportunity to play a game, as many times as you want, which has payoff equal to $K$ * $N$($\mu$,$\sigma^2$), where $K$ is a constant of your choice and $N$ an outcome of form a normal distribution with the given parameters that are fixed. You have $X$ available funds and if you reach a negative balance you can't play anymore. What is the optimal choice of $K$, in terms of $X$, $\mu$, and $\sigma$, in a Kelly Criterion sense, meaning that the strategy leads to higher wealth compared to any other strategy in the long run.

Comment: Just a couple of questions.  First, is the problem discrete or real valued? If it involves pennies, then it is certain that the portfolio will go to zero at least once if played to infinity. Second, since the normal distribution has support on the entire real line, so you mean the actual normal distribution or a truncated form of the normal?

Comment: @DaveHarris If you mean the pay-off then it's real-valued. Would the probability that the portfolio hits zero not also go to zero for any finite $\sigma$, since we could just make K small enough, as the trials go to infinity, almost surely? Would we have to start dealing with a risk aversion parameter if we don't truncate it?


But for the actual question, yes we could consider it to be a truncated normal distribution (with very long tails). That's more in line with what got me thinking about the problem anyhow.

Comment: I think I realize now you could not, of course, as K also affects variance (which is intended). Perhaps this problem is more complicated than I thought

Comment: you cannot get heavy tails with a normal distribution. Real valued solutions would have a solution, though I would have to think about it. Discrete solutions would, almost surely, hit the boundary conditions because you would get down to pennies at the end of a long run and couldn't divide it up into real subsets of a penny. At least once, you are nearly guaranteed to hit the boundary and lose with the final penny. Is this an element of a real problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: K affects the variance of the portfolio, but not of the payoffs.

Comment: @DaveHarris Sorry, I didn't mean heavy tails in the kurtosis sense, just meant that it would be a normal distribution truncated very far from the mean.

The question arose trying to figure out the optimal stakes to play for poker. Typically you model your edge in the terms of BB per 100 hands which considered normal distributed. One example would be a 2BB/100 hands win rate and a 100BB/100 hands variance. So the outcome of 100 hands comes from an N(2,100^2) distribution. Based on that, and a bankroll of X, how high stakes should you play?

Comment: E.g. you have X=1000 dollars, how much should each BB be worth. Do you think this is the correct approach to come up with an answer to that question?

Comment: No, poker has exact probabilities, the problem is bluffing. That makes it more complicated than a Kelly bet.  You would need to model bluffing into your probabilities. Solving over log-utility would produce the same impact as a Kelly bet. You need to solve for all bets, not just big bets. For a given set of gamblers with known individual histories, this is probably a solvable problem, but not a trivial problem.

Comment: @DaveHarris No, you're thinking about this on a too low level. I'm talking about your winnings after a *large* amount of hands played. Imagine a professional gambler playing 100,00 hands of poker. His winning at the end of those 100,00 hands could be modelled as coming from a normal distribution of some mean and variance. In my question each trial is 100 hands, and the payoff is the sum of the winnings from those hands (together being from a normal distribution).

Comment: yes, that would not be optimal. The Kelly bet is about how to bet in each single round. If the probability changes per round, then the bet changes with it, which is what professional players do. Have you looked at Louis M. Rotando & Edward O. Thorp (1992) The Kelly Criterion and the Stock Market, The American Mathematical Monthly, 99:10, 922-931

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't change in my example.The "bet" here would be which stakes you play, e.g. do you play with blinds worth 2 dollars or 4 dollars. Or otherwise put, which table do you sit down at.

But I will look over that paper, perhaps it goes over something close to what I'm talking about, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Some references.**

To supplement the comments of @Dave Harris, here are a cluster of references you might consider using to start further formalising what you've done already. Depending on your mathematical disposition:

1. Kelly's [original paper](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Ewbialek/rome/refs/kelly_56.pdf), *A New Interpetation of Information Rate (1956)*. This work stands out in terms of the elegance of the idea and simplicity of presentation.

2. The work of Thorp and associates. See for example:

*Thorp, E. O. (2008). The Kelly criterion in blackjack sports betting, and the stock market. Handbook of Asset and Liability Management, 385–428. doi:10.1016/b978-044453248-0.50015-0*

3. The work of probabilists in the 60s/70s. Here are some works to illustrate the kind of approach you have outlined using your formalism:

*Breiman, L. (1961). Optimal gambling systems for favorable games. Fourth Berkeley Symposium on probability and statistics, I, 65-78*

*Dubins, L., Savage, L. (1965). How to Gamble if You Must. New York, McGraw-Hill.*

Most of these works lie on the academic borders of mathematical statistics/probability and the mathematics of gambling. I have omitted works that have not been vetted by the academic community, such as practical gambling books, because these tend to be written at the level of a numerically literate, but not necessarily mathematically literate audience.  These books also tend to gloss over or use mathematical or statistical concepts somewhat sloppily.

An excellent mathematics of gambling book that does not overly simplify the mechanics of various casino games, and yet remains mathematically rigorous without using more sophisticated machinery (e.g. measure theory etc.) is the following:

*Ethier, S. (2010). The Doctrine of Chances: Probabilistic Aspects of Gambling*

---

**A general framework for optimal gambling in favourable games.**

I have no experience with studying the mathematics of poker, but have spent time reading the literature on using the Kelly criterion with HI-LO card counting in Blackjack.

Here is an extract of a general framework from Thorp (2008) used to illustrate the mechanics of the Kelly criterion asymptotically, and also in studying gambling in mathematics (with its roots in the references cited in 3.).

> Imagine that we are faced with an infinitely wealthy opponent who will wager even money bets made on repeated independent trials of a biased coin. Further suppose that on each trial our win probability is $p > 1/2$ and the probability of losing is $q = (1 - p)$. Our initial capital is $X_0$. Suppose we choose the goal of maximising the expected value $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ after $n$ trials. How much should we bet $B_k$ on each trial? Letting $T_k = 1$ if the $k$th trial is a win and $T_k = -1$ if it is a loss, then $X_k = X_{k-1} + T_k B_k$ for $k = 1, 2, \dots,$ and $X_n = X_0 + \sum^n_{k=1} T_k B_k$. Then
> $$\mathbb{E}[X_n] = X_0 + \sum^n_{k=1} \mathbb{E}[B_k T_k] = X_0 + \sum^n_{k=1} (p - q) \mathbb{E}[B_k]$$

Apart from the innovative metaphorical transfer of ideas in communications engineering to gambling, the optimal gambling literature frames the motivation for using the Kelly criterion for betting as a resolution (in an asymptotically optimal sense) to the following trade-off:

- That is, maximising expected gain $\mathbb{E}[B_k]$ in each trial by betting the maximum of our resources in each trial, thereby maximising $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$. The probability of bankruptcy (referred to as "ruin" in the literature) in this case is 1 (bankruptcy will occur almost surely).
- The opposing pole would be minimising the probability of eventual bankruptcy, which is equivalent to betting the minimum bet on each trial. This however minimises expected gain and therefore minimises $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$

In this simple framework, it can be shown that the Kelly criterion maximises $\mathbb{E}[\log X_n]$, by betting a fraction $f^* = p - q = 2p - 1$ in each round of one's capital. That is by setting $B_{k-1} = X_{i-1}f^* = X_{i-1}(2p - 1)$.

This is just an introductory framework, and various modifications can be made using this framework for dependent trials with varying win loss probabilities $p_k$ and $q_k$ (e.g. in Blackjack) etc. Furthermore the point @Dave Harris makes about the denomination of capital is important - because in these analyses, capital is assumed to be infinitely divisible, whereas the practical setting violates this assumption, in that we have a fixed minimum currency denomination that cannot be split (e.g. dollars, pounds etc.).

To extend this kind of analysis to poker, which is not played against the House, rather, other players, you might consider finding a way to characterise the expectation/probabilities in each round. This is easier said than done but any informed analysis will almost certainly require some game-theoretic specification of the outcomes given assumptions about other player behaviour. The Ethier book contains a section on Poker, but I cannot personally attest to it, only on the excellent contents of other chapters I have read.

In terms of attempting to estimate parameters $\mu, \sigma^2$ of a Normally distributed cumulative payoff after many rounds in an asymptotic setting (which is a departure from the above class of analysis from the optimal gambling literature, but similar in the use of the Normal distribution), here is a paper which might give you some ideas:

*Millman, M. H. (1983). A Statistical Analysis of Casino Blackjack. The American Mathematical Monthly, 90(7), 431.*

Lastly, a good informal website in general is:

https://wizardofodds.com/

This website gave fairly accurate computations when I reproduced Basic strategy calculations for Blackjack.